# html classes code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

So I'm not really sure what I'm looking for and don't know what to search, since I don't know the appropriate naming of it( if there exists any).

Anyway, I have some .aspx pages that have Groups of elements that look the same, styled with css, and I use them on many pages. Though on the different pages the surrounding html code differ and the code behind differ quite allot in the way they manipulate these elements.

My problem is that if I make a change in one .aspx page I have to go through all the other aspx pages and update them with the same change.

I'm looking to have this element, or html-block is maybe a more correct word, in one file and "reference" it from the different .aspx pages that use it.
I can do this with Iframe but then I can't access the different elements via code behind(or maybe I'm doing something wrong).

So if anybody can tell me what to search for or provide a link would be appreciated : )

Comment: How about wrapping them in a user control?

Comment: Search User Control in ASP.Net you will find a lot of appropriate links, [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET) and [Here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/).

Comment: [Master Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140).aspx) are also useful for setting the structure of your pages. [User controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.140).aspx) are useful when it's reusable elements that you need on your content page.

Comment: Thx! This seems to be what I was looking for : )